# convert uuid from bin in select * statment

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got an id column in my mysql table which contain a uuid in a binary(16) form , if i will select only this specific column like this:

```
SELECT uuid_from_bin(id) FROM table_name;
```

i will get the uuid properly but as soon as i try to select * like this:
`select * from table_name;` 
i'm getting the uuid in binary form.

i tried something like this:

```
SELECT uuid_from_bin(id),* FROM table_name;
```

but this gives me an error

Comment: And what error do you get? Please include full error message in the question.

Comment: Don't use `select *`. Specify only the columns you need. [Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: @ZoharPeled i need every column but the id should be converted to uuid that's all , i can specifiy every column by name but i thought there is more simple approach

Comment: It's bad practice to use `select *`, with a few exceptions here and there.

Comment: *"Don't use select *. Specify only the columns you need"* i totally agree @ZoharPeled to bad most database abstraction layers work like that and select all data from a record assuming you don't manually build your query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland that doesn't make it a good practice by any means. I personally avoid using full-scale ORM's partially because of performance issues....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, uuid_from_bin(id) as uuid FROM table_name;
```

Comment: it does work but i'm still getting the original id with the uuid in binary

Comment: I don't think that would be very straight forward. Why don't just ignore one extra column in the result?

Answer (score 0):

try to use alias for your table. in my example the alias is `t`

```
SELECT uuid_from_bin(t.id), t.* FROM table_name t;
```

if you need only specific columns, so do not use `*` in your `select`.
use only columns you need
e.g.

```
SELECT uuid_from_bin(t.id), t.col1, t.col2 ...
  FROM table_name t;
```

Comment: it does work but i'm still getting the original id with the uuid in binary

Comment: thats because you do `select * `, select only columns you need